# Как поменять яркость подсветки экрана через запись в файл sysfs?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Возникла проблема, при попытке изменить данные в системном файле `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness`.

Когда хочу изменить максимальную яркость выдает ошибку `error writing input/output error`.

Что можно с этим сделать? Может, есть другие способы решения изменить яркость на Radeon?

Comment: > данные в системном файле А у Вас какая ОС? Потому, что в fedora я наблюдаю такую картину: $ pwd /sys/class/backlight $ ls $ Нет там ничего...

Comment: @Sergey, там в метках у вопроса Arch Linux, вы, наверное, не заметили.

Answer (score 1):

А как вы собираетесь менять *максимальную* яркость подсветки дисплея? Ошибка `error writing` означает, что драйвер подсветки счел ваши данные, которые вы попытались записать, некорректными или, что более вероятно, запись в данный файл в принципе не поддерживается.

---

Чтобы изменить *текущую* яркость нужно писать в файл **`brightness`**, который лежит рядом с `max_brightness`, значения от 0 до *максимального*.

А вот само максимальное значение можно найти как раз в файле `max_brightness`.